# Converting an equation to the form $ax+by=c$

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation, expression-form

I have a linear equation that comes as a result of applying orthogonality on a non-homogeneous boundary condition with two unknowns $C_1$ and $C_2$. Can someone help me to express this equation in the form:

$$a(C_1) + b(C_2)=c\tag A$$

The code to derive the equation is as follows:

```
T[x_, y_, z_] = (C1* E^(γ z) + C2* E^(-γ z))*Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ] + Ta;
tc[x_, y_] = E^(-bcy/l)*{tci + (bc/l)*Integrate[E^(bc*s/l)*T[x, s, 0], {s, 0, y}]};
bc1 = (D[T[x, y, z], z] /. z -> 0) == pc (T[x, y, 0] - tc[x, y]);
ortheq1 = Integrate[(bc1[[1]] - bc1[[2]])*Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}, Assumptions -> {C1 > 0, C2 > 0, L > 0, l > 0, α > 0, β > 0, γ > 0, δ > 0, θ > 0, NTUC > 0, pc > 0, Ta > 0, tci > 0}] == 0;
```

One can also use the following to derive `ortheq1` but it gives a longer result

```
ortheq1 = Integrate[bc1[[1]]*Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}] == Integrate[bc1[[2]]*Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}];
```

It is the `ortheq1` that I would like in the form $(A)$.

Comment: If it is a polynomial in `C1` and `C2` use `CoefficientList`, else have a look at `Select` and `FreeQ`. Also `Collect[ortheq1, {C1, C2}]` might work.

Comment: Is the appearance of `List` (`{ }`) in the definition of `tc` on purpose?

Comment: @Natas No I just wanted to specify that it is a product of `E^(-bcy/l)`. I should have used `()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the appearance of `List` in the definition of `tc` is not on purpose, i.e.

```
T[x_, y_, z_] = (C1* E^(γ z) + C2* E^(-γ z))*Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ] + Ta;
tc[x_, y_] = E^(-bcy/l)*(tci + (bc/l)*Integrate[E^(bc*s/l)*T[x, s, 0], {s, 0, y}]);
bc1 = (D[T[x, y, z], z] /. z -> 0) == pc (T[x, y, 0] - tc[x, y]);
ortheq1 = Integrate[(bc1[[1]] - bc1[[2]])*Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}, Assumptions -> {C1 > 0, C2 > 0, L > 0, l > 0, α > 0, β > 0, γ > 0, δ > 0, θ > 0, NTUC > 0, pc > 0, Ta > 0, tci > 0}] == 0;
```

Then you can use `CoefficientList`

```
Module[{coeffs = CoefficientList[Subtract @@ ortheq1, {C1, C2}]},
  a[C1_] = coeffs[[2, 1]] C1;
  b[C2_] = coeffs[[1, 2]] C2;
  c = -coeffs[[1, 1]];
]
(Subtract @@ ortheq1) - (a[C1] + b[C2] - c) // Simplify
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But were you able to get the coefficients `a,b,c`. When I run your code it throws an error saying `Object of unequal length`, but the code kep t on running and gave an output. Now should i access $a$ using `a[C1]` , $b$ as `b[C2]` ? And how can I access `c` ?

Comment: Have you run the code I have posted? My definition of `tc` is different than yours (no `List` as discussed in the comments above). It should not give an error. You can then simply access `a` and `b` as functions and `c` is a "constant". The last line demonstrates this, where I show that the result is correct.

Comment: Oh I think I just added the second part of your answer to my original code. I will run your version from the start. Thanks again.

Comment: worked perfectly. Thanks, this was really helpful. I tried the whole procedure on my other `ortheq2` and was successful there too.

Comment: May I ask, the reason behind the recent edit to the answer where you included `Subtract` ? Is it supposed to provide improved performance ?

Comment: When doing the edit I was only considering readability. However, it seems that it is also more efficient: `With[{eqs = Table[RandomReal[] \[FormalX] == 1, 10^6]}, (First@ Timing@#[eqs] &) /@ {Subtract @@@ #; &, #[[1]] - #[[2]] & /@ #; &}]` gives `{0.516, 1.6}`.

Comment: Appreciate the response and the explanation.